# How to match any pattern to a any string using Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, string-matching

I would like to create a function in Ruby which accepts the following parameters:

- A *pattern string* (e.g. "abab", "aabb", "aaaa", etc.)
- An *input string* (e.g. "dogcatdogcat", "carcarhousehouse", etc.)

The return of the function should be *"true"* if the string matches the pattern and *"false"* if not.

**My approach for the first step:**

Use regex in order to separate the input string into an array of words (e.g. *["dog", "cat", "dog", "cat"]*).

My regex expertise is not good enough to be able to find the right regex for this problem.

Does anyone know how to perform the appropriate regex so that recurring words get separated assuming the input string is always some form of pattern?

Comment: Is the input string purely random? Or does it only contain words from a fixed dictionary?

Comment: @spickermann The input string is purely random

Comment: If the input string is `anhydrous`, what should the result be, considering that `a` is a word in the English language, `an` is a word in the English language, `hydro` is a word in the English language, `us` is a word in the English language, `hydrous` is a word in the English language, and `anhydrous` is a word in the English language? What about `starfish`, `alphanumeric`, `podcast`, `webcast`, `wardriving`, `airplane`, `sailplane`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capture groups and backreferences to match the same substring multiple times, e.g.:

```
abab = /\A(.+)(.+)\1\2\z/
aabb = /\A(.+)\1(.+)\2\z/
aaaa = /\A(.+)\1\1\1\z/

'dogcatdogcat'.match?(abab) #=> true
'dogcatdogcat'.match?(aabb) #=> false
'dogcatdogcat'.match?(aaaa) #=> false

'carcarhousehouse'.match?(abab) #=> false
'carcarhousehouse'.match?(aabb) #=> true
'carcarhousehouse'.match?(aaaa) #=> false
```

In the above pattern, `(.+)` defines a capture group that matches one or more characters. `\1` then refers to the 1st capturing group and matches the same substring. (`\2` is the 2nd group and so on)

`\A` and `\z` are anchors to match the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer! This is definitely heading into the right direction! The only issue is that the pattern string is not limited to the combinations you listed. The pattern string could include any character and any length. I am guessing the regex has to be somehow dynamically built at runtime?

Comment: @rowingdan you can absolutely do that. And constructing the regex out of your pattern strings is pretty straight-forward: the first occurrence of each letter becomes `(.+)` and every subsequent occurrence becomes the corresponding index, e.g. `\1` for `a`, `\2` for `b` etc.